# Customizing Bulma navbar-item using SASS

Tags: html, css, bulma

What is the SASS variable to customize the font-size of a Buma navbar-item? I've searched in Bulma's navbar.sass but font-size only exist for the navbar-dropdown.

Comment: there isn't, just add your own css there

Comment: it inherits $body-font-size by default

Comment: @JunaidShaikh If you flesh out your comment just a little bit, maybe with an example, this will be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Bulma, there is no specific SASS variable available to customize the font size of a navbar item directly. However, you can achieve this by adding your own custom CSS rules to target the navbar item class or element.

By default, the font size of a navbar item in Bulma inherits from the $body-font-size SASS variable, which sets the base font size for the entire document. To customize the font size of navbar items, you can add CSS rules like .navbar-item { font-size: 18px; } to your project's stylesheet.

This allows you to override the default font size inherited from $body-font-size and achieve the desired styling for your navbar items.